# Wso2is cluster wrong doc

Tags: wso2, wso2-as, wso2-identity-server

I’m following this doc:
https://docs.wso2.com/m/view-rendered-page.action?abstractPageId=85367416.

But i’m very confuse because :

1. in the carbon.xml it tells to write wso2.is.com like alias.
2. in the site.json and web.xml to write is.wso2.com
3. and at the end in nginx configuration as.wso2.com

Which is the differences? Is there sometingh wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Thanx for reporting. This should be corrected and should use one of the hostnames across all the configurations.

Comment: @Pubci so i should use, for example, “is.wso2is.com” in carbon.xml and nginx configuration?

Comment: Yes, same hostname across all the configs.